# Android byte array batches

Tags: java, android

I am sending image through Bluetooth pro-grammatically. When i send image as Byte array at the sending side the byte array length is = 83402 and at the receiving side i am getting byte bacthes of 1024.

I want to combine these 1024 batches into single byte array so that i again convert it as an image.

Here in the msg.obj i get 1024 bacth of byte array.

case MESSAGE_READ:

```
 byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;

 Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(readBuf,0,readBuf.length);
```

After that i am also getting this warning..

"Default buffer size used in BufferedOutputStream constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k buffer is required"

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Should be roughly something like this:

```
byte[] readBuf = new byte[83402]; // this array will hold the bytes for the image, this value better be not hardcoded in your code

int start = 0;
while(/*read 1024 byte packets...*/) {
    readBuf.copyOfRange((byte[]) msg.obj, start, start + 1024); // copy received 1024 bytes
    start += 1024; //increment so that we don't overwrite previous bytes
}

/*After everything is read...*/
Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(readBuf,0,readBuf.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and assume you're using the [BluetoothChat example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html) from the sdk to build your image sender (all your examples match it).  Here's a quick conversion I threw together - may not be the best but it works.

You're getting them in batches of 1024 because in the BluetoothChatService.java run function it creates a buffer array size 1024 that goes and gets info from the input stream. If you create another buffer that will fit the image there (I set a max 1mb) then your run function would have:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
byte[] imgBuffer = new byte[1024*1024];
int pos = 0;
```

with your pos variable keeping track of where you are in your imgBuffer.

Then you just copy it over while you're getting chunks in the while(true) loop of the image like this (mmInStream is an InputStream):

```
int bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
System.arraycopy(buffer,0,imgBuffer,pos,bytes);
pos += bytes;
```

I send a message to let it know that the image is done sending and at that point shuttle the imgBuff over to the other thread (pos has the size of the imgBuffer at this point):

```
mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.IMAGE_READ, pos, -1, imgBuffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
```

I had defined IMAGE_READ to decode the array like you did in your MESSAGE_READ:

```
byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
```